# Servidor local no accesible desde mi aplicación local

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, azure

Estoy trabajando con **asp.net core 3.1**.

Subí mi aplicación y base de datos a *Azure*, hasta ahí me funciona bien, pero necesito seguir trabajando sobre mi proyecto, cuando compilo me sale un error que el servidor no fue encontrado o no está accesible, reinicié los servicios de *SQL* pensando que ese era el problema pero no lo es. Cuando intento eliminar la base de datos desde la consola *VS* me sale el mismo error y me doy cuenta que está apuntando al servidor de *Azure*.

¿Porqué me pasa esto si no configuré el firewall en *Azure* para acceder desde *SQL*?

En el archivo *appsetting.json* tengo configurado así

```
"MyStringConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=MyBD;Integrated Security=true"
```

Saludos!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: cuando publicas tu app en Azure te da la opcion para configurar la cadena de conexion de tu base de datos en Azure, lo hiciste?

Comment: no me queda claro si tenes un 404 cuando pones la direccion, es error de conexion de su app con la base de datos

Comment: Gracias por responder, el problema está cuando hago algunas modificaciones a mi código y quiero probar en mi local, quedó grabado el server de azure en al guna parte que no me toma mi server local.

Comment: Cuando publiqué en Azure si configuré la cadena de conexión y me funciona bien no tengo ningún problema en esa parte. Lo que no entiendo porque esa cadena de conexión quedó grabada en mi local que ahora cada vez que compilo trata de conectarse el server en Azure cuando debería buscar mi server local.